# how to skip record if its null

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to know how i can skip a record without getting no data found error when A_NUMBER has null value ?

i found continue key word but it was not work on my oracle 10g and I tried by  counting the number of record returned but thats was not useful here is how i tried hope there is better way to do it

```
declare
A_num_id varchar2 (25);
num1 number(4);
cursor nums_cur is select A_NUMBER from free_check;

begin 

for nums_rec in nums_cur loop
select count(*) into num1 from user_info where co_num=nums_rec.A_NUMBER;

select customer_id into A_num_id from user_info where co_num=nums_rec.A_NUMBER; 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A_num_id is '||A_num_id);

end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to wrap the user_info query in a plsql block with an exception handler.

```
    begin
       select customer_id into A_num_id from user_info where co_num=nums_rec.A_NUMBER;
    exception
      when no_data_found then ...
    end;
```

But if the loop selects too many records the performance is not optimal. Best way is to change your free_check cursor and join user_info into the query. That way the cursor will only select records for which a user_info record exists.

Comment: I cant use join coz i need to know the ful result the user who has an a_number and who does not has a_number join will not show the full reslut except i used full join which will get me back to same point.. and that what i am asking for i tried to add continue key word at exception part but it works only with oracle 11g.. right ?

Comment: What's wrong with this join?

select i.*
  from free_check f
      ,user_info  i
 where f.a_number = i.co_num

Comment: if a_number is null ill never know that when using join and if i use full join to get this case ill get back to the point where a_number is null.. am I right ?

Comment: You really have to think about the meaning of the data in your database. What does it mean when a_number is null? Are you really interested in those records or can you skip them?

Comment: yes the a_number can be null for few customer but sometimes for some reason this record should not be null for specific user and thats what im checking if there are users with no a_number but they are acutely  should have an a_number that the main idea of my check... so I should report all user who has a_number and the user swho doesnt have in order to take dissension about them..

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be for you to modify the cursor and select only `A_NUMBER` values, which have `user_info` data, as below:

```
cursor nums_cur is 
select A_NUMBER from free_check fc
where exists
(
select 1
from user_info ui
where ui.co_num = fc.A_NUMBER
);
```